# When golang does allocation for string to byte conversion

Tags: go, allocation

```
var testString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
//var testString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
func BenchmarkHashing900000000(b *testing.B){
    var bufByte = bytes.Buffer{}
    for i := 0; i < b.N ; i++{
        bufByte.WriteString(testString)
        Sum32(bufByte.Bytes())
        bufByte.Reset()
    }
}

func BenchmarkHashingWithNew900000000(b *testing.B){
    for i := 0; i < b.N ; i++{
        bytStr := []byte(testString)
        Sum32(bytStr)
    }
}
```

test result:

```
With  testString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
BenchmarkHashing900000000-4         50000000            35.2 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkHashingWithNew900000000-4  50000000            30.9 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op

With testString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
BenchmarkHashing900000000-4         30000000            46.6 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkHashingWithNew900000000-4  20000000            73.0 ns/op        64 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Why there is allocation in case of BenchmarkHashingWithNew900000000 when string is long but no allocation when string is small.
Sum32 : https://gowalker.org/github.com/spaolacci/murmur3
**I am using go1.6**

Answer (score 4):

Your benchmarks are observing a curious optimisation by the Golang compiler (version 1.8).

You can see the PR from Dmitry Dvyukov here

https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/3120

Unfortunately that is from a long time ago, when the compiler was written in C, I am not sure where to find the optimisation in the current compiler. But I can confirm that it still exists, and Dmitry's PR description is accurate.

If you want a clearer self contained set of benchmarks to demonstrate this I have a gist here.

https://gist.github.com/fmstephe/f0eb393c4ec41940741376ab08cbdf7e

If we look only at the second benchmark `BenchmarkHashingWithNew900000000` we can see a clear spot where it 'should' allocate.

```
bytStr := []byte(testString)
```

This line must copy the contents of `testString` into a new `[]byte`. However in this case the compiler can see that `bytStr` is never used again after `Sum32` returns. Therefore it can be allocated on the stack. However, as strings can be arbitrarily large a limit is set to 32 bytes for a stack allocated `string` or `[]byte`.

It's worth being aware of this little trick, because it can be easy to trick yourself into believing some code does not allocate, if your benchmark strings are all short.

Answer (score -1):

When you write something into a `byte.Buffer`, it allocates memory as needed. When you call `byte.Buffer.Reset`, that memory is not freed but instead kept for later reuse. And your code does exactly that. It marks the buffer as empty and then fills it again.

Actually, there *is* some allocation going on, but when iterating 50000000 times, it is negligible. But if you move the declaration for `bufByte` into the `for` loop, you will get some allocations.

Comment: This is what i would expect. Except above bench mark shows for smaller string, there is no allocation in both the cases. But it behaves as expected for bigger string.

Comment: You should have a look at the compiled code. `go test -c` and then `go tool objdump -s 'BenchmarkHashing' main.test.exe`.

Comment: @VishalKumar You actually shouldn't see an allocation in _either_ case for the `bytes.Buffer` version.  Bytes.Buffer has a built-in 64-byte array in its structure for handling small data sets without (extra) allocation, and neither of those tests exceed 64 bytes per write operation.  If you move the `bufByte.Reset()` outside the for loop, I have a feeling you'll see more equitable results.

Comment: @Kaedys Question is not about why no allocation for bytes.Buffer. There will be single allocation outside loop. It is as expected in result. Question is why not allocation for other case when string is small.

Comment: Thinking about it, I have a hunch you're seeing a compiler optimization, tbh.  Try assigning the value in that `bytStr` slice to another global slice to prevent the compiler from optimizing it out.  As long as you're assigning to a defined global slice variable (_NOT_ appending to the global slice), there shouldn't be any extra allocation for that assignment, just the filling of a pointer and the setting of a pair of ints in the slice header.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/FchGznDWNC